# Xcode 9, Size Inspector, Autoresizing, and Safe Area Relative Margins

Tags: xcode, resize, iphone-x

Is there any way to get Size Inspector autoresizing to work properly with iPhones of both rectangular and curved/notch dimensions? I had suspected that selecting "Safe Area Relative Margins" would set autoresizing to the safe area, but the graphic below shows it doesn't seem to take this into account. Deselecting "Safe Area Relative Margins" doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect. I know I could add constraints, but am curious if this is a bug, I'm missing something, or if this is a feature that just won't work with iPhone X. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: is there any solution to this . ?